# Select Random Value MYSQL But Not Current Value

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have the following code to pull a random value from a database.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column1 FROM table1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['column1'];
 echo "<br>";
}
```

At the moment I only have about 10 values in total. Sometimes they appear more than once in a row upon refresh.

Can the query be amended to show a random value that is not the current value?

Comment: Random means repeated values some times.  What you want is not random.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer: Can you predict the order?

Comment: Random is not the same as unpredictable either.  I can roll a die repeatedly and if the result is truly random, it may roll 6 more than once in a row (in fact, it might be 4 or more times in a row) and still be random and unpredictable.

Comment: Anyway, if you want unpredictable, but nonrepeated values, you store the id for the last one generated and add it as an exclusion to your while clause.

Comment: Thanks guys. Interesting discussion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to do that you need to somehow remember the last row.
Then do something like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column1 FROM table1
where id_of_your_row != ".mysqli_real_escape_string($id_of_your_last_row)."
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");
```

For remembering the last row, you could use sessions.

Your whole code could look like this.

// sessions need to bestarted

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT column1 FROM table1
where column1 != ".(isset($_SESSION["lastid"]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION["lastid"]) : '')." ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row['column1'];
 $_SESSION["lastid"] = $row['column1'];
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to pull out any values. Is there an obvious typo?